# Msg 21, Level 21, State 1, Line 1 Warning: Fatal error 9001

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We recently moved to a SQL Server that's on a VPS and every now and then we get a 9001 error when trying to do an update.

Rebooting the server fixes the problem.

I changed the maximum server memory (in MB) to 2000 because it's a 4GB VPS.

But I just don't know what's causing the error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is your database set to auto-close? If auto-close is on your database shuts itself down and the update statement would then cause the database to come back online, kick off automatic system checks, and could raise this error if the update statement comes in at the same time.

What other SQL Server error messages are coming in at or around the same time as the 9001 error?

What Windows error messages are coming at around the same time? Are there any error messages for your underlying disk structure? This error can be caused by disk failure as well.

Answer (score 11):

That error means that the log for your database (or for tempdb) is not avaialble for some reason.  That's a serious problem that is usually fixed by restarting the server.

If the problem recurs, it could be many things having to do with problems with your storage system.  One possible thing to check is to see if your database's log file (or tempdb's log file) is running out of space (not sure if that can cause this error or not).

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are on the latest service pack version of SQL Server 2008.

Restarting SQL Server is just duct taping the problem. I would suggest you to collect diagnostic information using SQLDiag when the problem actually occurs.

Also, run a **DBCC CHECKDB** against the database so that it will give you more info about the corruption. A last resort would be to run a CHECK DISK (chkdsk) to see if the OS sees any problem with the disk subsystem.

Max memory setting has nothing to do with 9001 error.

Answer (score -3):

take your database offline then online will resolve your issue....
also set autoclose to false

Comment: How is the former better then restarting, what the OP already tried several times?  And did you notice that the latter was already said in the accepted answer?